# In eclipse, how to display inherited members in Outline view?

Tags: java, eclipse, ide

Typing Ctrl+O twice in editor when a java type is selected pops-up an outline context dialog that displays the members && inherited members. How can I have this in the main outline view?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Looks like you can't do it.

Maybe you should file it as an improvement request.

Answer (score 20):

right click -> Open Type Hierarchy?

It does not show it in the same pane but I think you can see what you're looking for.

Comment: Make sure the 'Show All Inherited Members' button is activated

Comment: It's a bit painful that you have to press something to view it... It would be so much easier if it could always be somewhere on the side like outline pane and update automatically when another file/class opened.

Answer (score 15):

This is currently (Eclipse 3.6 Helios) not possible in outline view, but you can achieve similiar functionality through "Type Hierarchy" view:

1. Assuming you have opened a class that you want to inspect
2. Press F4 - this will open the "Type Hierarchy" view for that class
3. "Type hierarchy" view is divided to two parts - an upper one which contains the hierarchy itself and the lower one, which contains members of the selected class
4. In the lower view you can set the filter to show also all inherited members (a button with hint "Show All Inherited members")

Personally I belive that same filter should be available even in the outline view, but at least it is somewhere ;)

Answer (score 10):

There is a feature request already, but there are not enough votes for it...

https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=8625

Answer (score 6):

You should try **Type Hierarchy**.
Right Click the class and Open Type Hierarchy.
There are so many option look for **Show all inherited members**.
It can be found at the lover **section of the Type Hierarchy Widget**.

Comment: But how to quickly find to which of parrent classes a particular virtual method belongs (was declared in)? I mean, without actually browsing all parrent classes?Visual Studio had that since version 6.0, I guess.

Comment: It's listed behind the member in Eclipse Kepler and above (don't know this for elder versions)